# How to refer to a subsection of a starred section?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, starred-version

In [How to \label-\ref an un-numbered section](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62742/how-to-label-ref-an-un-numbered-section), Nathan Grigg pointed out that one could use the `\hyperref` commmand to create a link to a starred section as follows

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\section*{Preface to the article}
\label{s:intro}
\hyperref[s:intro]{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

*My* question now is how to create a link to a *numbered subsection* of that starred section?

Comment: Using `\phantomsection`?

Comment: Why not cross-reference such a subsection the usual way, i.e., via `\label` and `\ref` (or `\autoref`)? The "number" that gets used in such a cross-reference will look slightly odd, but that's because subsection numbers look odd too.

Comment: How do you number subsections of an unnumbered section?

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, it was egreg's comment that gave me the hint. This is using `cleveref` AFTER `hyperref`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
    \crefname{subsection}{Subsection}{Subsections}
\begin{document}
\chapter{ONE}\label{1-0-0}
\section*{Starred Section}\label{STR:1-0-0}
\subsection{First subsection of the starred section}\label{STR:1-0-1}
\section{First \emph{Non}-Starred Section}\label{1-1-0}
\subsection{First subsection of the first \emph{non}-starred section}\label{1-1-1}

\cref{STR:1-0-1} \nameref{STR:1-0-1} of the \hyperref[STR:1-0-0]{Starred Section} of \cref{1-0-0} \nameref{1-0-0}  on \cpageref{1-0-0}

\cref{1-1-1} \nameref{1-1-1} of  \cref{1-1-0} \nameref{1-1-0}   \labelcref{1-1-0} of \cref{1-0-0} \nameref{1-0-0}  on \cpageref{1-0-0}

\end{document}
```

[image: SubStarredSection]

Comment: But what if the starred section occurs *after* one or more numbered sections, with more numbered sections following?