# Suppressing section numbering AND referencing with \label

Tags: cross-referencing

Trying to reference a section WITHOUT having section numbers present. Possible?

The following:

```
\subsection*{Fulbright}
\label{subsec:fulbright}

... 
Fulbright Scholarship (see Section \hyperlink{myLink}{\ref{subsec:fulbright}} below).
```

obviously yields the error,

```
Package hyperref Warning: Suppressing empty link on input line 57.
```

Comment: You could use the command `nameref`provided by `hyperref` as [suggested here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62762/184389).

Comment: hmmm definitely closer! I may have to settle with " please see the corresponding subsection in the \ref{sec:Research Experience} section" since my subsection title is rather complicated and would take the focus away from wherer I want it. For instance, this subsection is within the larger research experience section, and each subsection is titled like a resume item (\subsection*{NAF-Fulbright Scholar at the University of Groningen 
\newline
(August 2019 — Present)}
\label{subsec:fulbright}

Comment: If the section name is too long, you could rephrase your text reference as something like "`See the Fulbright section on page~\pageref`".  You might also have to add an anchor if this section is not on the same page as the previous "linkable" reference.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand what you're planning to call Section myLink here, but you could try

```
\subsection*{Fulbright}
\hypertarget{subsec:fulbright}{}
...
Fulbright scholarship (see Section \hyperlink{subsec:fulbright}{myLink})
```