# Using \nameref to refer to an unlabeled section doesn't work

Tags: sectioning, cross-referencing, nameref

I want to reference to my `\section*{Foo.}` with the `\label{sec:foo}`. For this, I tried using `\nameref{sec:foo}` but it doesn't work, i.e. there are no errors but it just doesn't print anything at that place. It works for `\section{Foo.}` but not for my case although I did the same as described in this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62762/267360).
Any ideas what could be the problem?

Edit:

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{nameref}

\begin{document}
    
\section*{One.}
\label{sec:one}

\section*{Two.}

\nameref{sec:one}

\end{document}
```

It seems using nameref together with titlesec and a unnumbered section is the problem.

Comment: Did you try exactly this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62745/14757?

Comment: [This code](https://pastebin.com/raw/XaWdjmFV) produces [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQy7E.png) showing it should work. If your document is different, please provide a [complete, but minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764) that replicates your problematic behaviour. Can you do that?